# Register type in StructureMap when requested

Tags: c#, structuremap

We have a caching solution which relies on StructureMap to provide the correct cache implementation to developers. I'm trying to reduce the amount of StructureMap configuration needed, but have gotten stuck... The cache providers (such as local cache, distributed, ...) all implement the interface `ICache<T>`, and types are registered against different "cache profiles" as per the need for cross-server consistency. A profile is then mapped agains some cache provider. Currently, it is required to specify for each type cached how it should be cached, which gives a lot of lines like these in initialization:

```
CacheSetup.CacheType<Foo>.With<LocalMemoryCache>();
CacheSetup.CacheType<Bar>.With<LocalMemoryCache>();
CacheSetup.CacheType<Baz>.With<DistributedCache>();
```

Each of these lines basically fetches the cache provider for the requested profile and the registers that provider (implementation of `ICache<T>`) for that type.

What I want to do, is to be able to set a default cache profile that will be used for types that are not explicitly registered. In the above example, I'd like to set `LocalMemoryCache` to the default profile, and then when `GetInstance<ICache<Foo>>` is called, it should be resolved by the cache provider associated with that profile. I've been reading the documentation extensivly, especially the interception parts, but there doesn't seem to be a way to intercept **before** the instance is created, which I would need.

Any ideas how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Look at OnCreation, maybe it would be helpful

Comment: @gabba: As I understand it, `OnCreation` is also run after the instance is created. In my case, I will get an error because there is no defined way to construct the instance. Have I missed some way of using it?

Comment: No, you are right. Now I got what do you wants.Are you look for some onGetInstance event or GetInstance override? In that case you can wrap or intercept GetInstance functionality or make youreslf factory that provide that functionality and use it everywhere. Can you provide more detailed example?

Comment: Wow. I think I got it to work. Not quite in the way I envisioned it from the beginning, but still... I used the functionality to initialize with a function (`For(typeof(ICache<>)).Use(MyMagicMethod)`) that does some lookup. I'm going to have to think about if there are performance implications for this, though - it seems it is run every time I request an instance (not cached internally in structuremap, maybe not surprising), and does a bit of reflection...